# Does iPhoto hang on to images when Optimise Mac Storage setting is used in Photos.app?

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

Situation:

- I've migrated from using *iPhoto* to *Photos.app* on the Mac.
- I am using iCloud Photo Library
- I have both a MacBook and an iPhone connected to the iCloud Photo Library
- Both devices have the `Optimise [Device] Storage` setting enabled

I've read [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204476) from Apple, so I know that although Finder shows both the iPhoto and Photos libraries as 'using' a similar amount of storage, they're actually sharing the same, underlying image files.

I'm also aware that after migrating from iPhoto to Photos, I can continue to use iPhoto, but any changes there will not be reflected in Photos...

**My question** originates from the point at which I turned on `Optimise Mac Storage` on the Mac...

The MacBook in question is low on storage, so, as I continue to add photos (for example, I've imported some from an external drive), the overall space available on the Mac's HD is being kept in check by the *optimise* setting.

When I originally opened Photos.app, both the iPhoto and Photos libraries, in Finder, were roughly equal at ~25 GB. After turning on the optimise setting and importing new photos into Photos.app, you can see in the image below, the Photos Library is now lower, at 17.8 GB:

[image]

- Will iPhoto hang on to the 25 GB?
- Can iPhoto work alongside the *optimise storage* setting?
- At some point, the iCloud Photo Library optimisation may decide to move *older* photos off the Mac, that are in that iPhoto Library... what happens then?

Note: the Mac in this situation belongs to my wife. I'm keeping iPhoto around for a while, during the transition (some photo books being worked on, etc.). So it's kinda academic, because sooner or later I won't need iPhoto. But I'd be interested if anyone knows how the local library works alongside iCloud Photo Library, with *optimise* turned on.